# Batch to copy specific text from multiple files into one file based on a map

Tags: batch-file

I have 15 input files and a map that says which input file should each output line come from. The input files all look the same:

```
1,some numbers
2,some numbers
...
2000,some numbers
```

The map file looks like

```
1, filename1
2, filename1
3, filename7
...
2000, filename4
```

I want to create one output file that consists of 2000 lines which were copied from the input files based on the map i.e. output lines 1 and 2 were copied from filename1, line 3 was copied from filename3, ... and line 2000 was copied from filename4.

Can you please help me figure out how to use the map? 
I think my code should be something like

```
for i = 1 to 2000

   currentInputFileName = (read i-th line from the map 
                           to figure out input file name)

   findstr "%i," /b %currentInputFileName% > %outputFile%

next i
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is correct, but you have a couple minor errors: the number of line must be taken from *the first token* in the lines in map.txt file, and the filename is the second token. You could use your same code, but in such a case you must eliminate line numbers from `map.txt` file. Otherwise, you may eliminate the `counter` variable from the code and the space between the number and the filename in `map.txt` file.

Besides, you use a couple constructs that are particularly slow:

- `call` subroutine is slow. Is better to place the subroutine code inside the `for` and use Delayed Expansion to get the variables.
- The append redirection `>>` is slow because the output file is open and closed *each time* that a line is appended to it. It is much faster a normal `>` redirection.

This code should run much faster than the original; it uses the original format in `map.txt` file: `1,filename1`, etc.

```
@echo off

(FOR /f "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%G IN (map.txt) DO (
   findstr /b "%%G," "%%H"
)) > output.txt
```

Comment: If this answer aids you, you may select it as Best Answer and later, when you have enough rep points, also upvote it. This is the way we use in this site to say "thanks".

Comment: Better to use `tokens=1*`, just in case a comma appears in the file name.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing it like this

```
@echo off

SET count=1
FOR /f %%G IN (map.txt) DO (call :subroutine "%%G")
GOTO :eof

:subroutine
   findstr /b "%count%," %1 >> output.txt
   set /a count+=1
   GOTO :eof
```

Not sure if this is optimal in terms of speed. My input files actually contain not 2000 lines but 2000 blocks, each block 120 lines

```
1,1,some numbers
1,2,some numbers
...
1,120,some numbers
...
2000,120,some numbers
```

Is there a way to write this code to run faster?

Comment: does that really do what you want? There's nothing to get the filenames from `map.txt`.

Comment: I modified the     map.txt file to only contain input file names